# Why Validations Error doesn't show in the view

Tags: angular

Just practicing I have this form: It does make the console message so at least the wiring is correct but it doesn't show a validation error when I don't type anything in the textbook and hit submit.

```
  <form [formGroup]="myForm"
        (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)">
    <div>
      <label for="skuInput">SKU</label>
      <input id="skuInput" type="text" [formControl]="myForm.controls['sku']"   placeholder="sku">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

and this component for it:

```
export class DemoFormSkyWithBuilderComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  sku: AbstractControl;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = fb.group({
      sku: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this.sku = this.myForm.controls.sku;
  }
  onSubmit(value: string): void {
      console.log('you submitted this vallue: ' , value);
    }
```

Comment: you need add some like `<span *ngIf="mtForm.controls['sky'].errors>Required</span>`. NOTE. You can use `formControlName='sku'` instead of `[formControl]="mtForm.controls['sku']"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest Angular versions use `formControlName` instead of `formGroup`.

```
 <form [formGroup]="myForm"
        (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)">
    <div>
      <label for="skuInput">SKU</label>
      <input id="skuInput" type="text" formControlName="sku" placeholder="sku">
    </div>
    <p *ngIf="myForm.controls['sku'].errors.required">Field is required<p>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

In your component, in order to check whether the validation have been passed, use status property. This property allows you to access the current status of the form group instance.

If it returns `VALID` then validations have been passed else it will return `INVALID`.

```
export class DemoFormSkyWithBuilderComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  sku: AbstractControl;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = fb.group({
      sku: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
  onSubmit(value: string): void {
      console.log('Status: ' , this.myForm.status);
  }
```

Further more, if you wish to access a fields value, simply use:

```
this.myform.get('sku').value; //====> Enter field name, in this case sku
```

Similarly, to set the value of a field dynamically, you can do this:

```
this.myform.get('sku').setValue('Sku2');
```

It should work now. To know more about form validation, visit Angular's offical website [here](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation).

Comment: Thanks for 'formControlName' I like it better. The older style I was learning I didn't like it either. This is better.... But what is "value.status"

Comment: Its cool no worries! the status is used to check the forms status . FOr more readablity just try this,form.status, it will return valid and invalid depending on the validations completed or not

Comment: oh I see ... to get the method working I had to also change it to onSubmit(form)  .. it used to be form.value

Comment: For more information on form validation. check out https://angular.io/guide/form-validation